# Upload and download documents from database through WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Can someone provide some samples of how to upload and download documents which are stored in a database using WCF?

I've seen samples online but they are all reading from the file system, file being stored on the web server. I need to be able to upload a document into the database instead (db filetype is varbinary(max)).

I've seen using a webservice the file being passed as Byte[], from what i'm read online that seems to be causing a file size restriction when using WCF, anyone know if that's true? otherwise I'll try to pass the file into the WCF Service as a Byte[].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [streaming transfer mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx) in WCF? It adds a few restrictions but if you are ok with them, it will help you get around the size restriction.

Examples on how to stream blobs from and to an SQL Server database can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I'm still new to WCF, is there a working sample on how to stream a file to and from the database with WCF?

Comment: @Paritosh Follow the steps from this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx Ignore the last part with the custom stream.

Answer (score 0):

That's what I do... I use Byte[] to send documents......

if the size is too big.... you just need to adjust the default max bytes in your WCF config file

```
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2000000"
    maxArrayLength="2000000" maxBytesPerRead="2000000" maxNameTableCharCount="2000000" />
```

Comment: whats the max size you have been able to upload, we'll be meeting soon with our users to get an idea of what filetypes and sizes they would upload, i just want to make sure the size being too large isn't going to cause any issues.

Comment: I use it for a custom software updater that created to download files to the user's machine.  I am not sure of the biggest size of upload, but using this value, I usually don't have an issue.  Do you know what the max size is that you will be uploading?

Comment: Not sure, we are meeting with our users later this week, hopefully they will be able to give us an idea.  Do you know what the default size restriction is, 4mb?

Comment: here's the default:            <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880"
            maxArrayLength="200000" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />